# Type casting in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, casting, nstimeinterval

Is there any way how can i convert a nstimeinterval type value to a string type in xcode?

Thanks in advance
Joy

Comment: probably it would help if you use the actual objective-c type names, it would be easier to figure out what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An NSTimeInterval is a `double`. You could use

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", timeInterval];
```

for more sophisticated format (e.g. "2 minutes 40 seconds"), write your own function.